# How to remove Linux from my system without affecting Windows' bootloader?

Tags: windows, linux, grub, uninstall

I'm a Windows user. I tried to experiment with Linux and installed openSUSE on my system. I formatted a partition and installed Linux on that drive.

When I tried to remove Linux by formatting that drive, on the next boot, Windows wouldn't load.

Some GRUB bootloader error is displaying. I reinstalled Linux and everything was working fine again. So, how do I remove Linux from my system (from that drive) without affecting Windows' bootloader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reinstall the Windows boot loader. Use your Windows CD, choose the recovery option, and get to a command prompt. Then based on the Windows version you should run `fixboot` and `fixmbr` or `Bootrec.exe/FixMbr`.

More reading:

- [Uninstall Grub BootLoader via Windows XP CD](http://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-the-Grub-Bootloader-from-a-Dual-Boot-XP-System-With-an-XP-CD)
- [Remove Grub Bootloader to get Windows 7 Loader Back](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/34709-how-remove-grub-loader-get-windows-7-boot-loader-back-uninstalling-linux.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by formating the Linux partitions and  create unallocated space in the disk manager. After that boot the computer with the windows cd in the cd-rom. It may take a few minutes to load.  Select 'Recovery Console' by pressing 'r' choose Windows system and log into it

```
Press enter to bypass the administrative password prompt.
Type fixboot and press enter.
Type y to confirm choice and press enter.
Type fixmbr and press enter.
Type y to confirm choice and press enter.
Then retype fixboot and press enter.
Type y to confirm choice and press enter.
Type exit and press enter.
```

Answer (score 1):

Boot from Linux and install the package:

```
 sudo apt-get install syslinux
```

If the package was installed, use the following to write the MBR.

```
 sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
```

If it does not work, boot from Linux and install this package:

```
 sudo apt-get install mbr
```

Use this to write the MBR:

```
 sudo install-mbr -i n -p D -t 0 /dev/sda
```

To check, use:

```
 sudo fdisk -l
```